# MySQL Data Provider for VS 2005 & 2010

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, mysql-connector

I have VS 2005 ( for legacy apps) and VS 2010 (for new development) installed on my machine.
To connect mysql through server explorer for typed dataset, I have installed connector 6.5.4 ( recent). It is appearing in VS 2010 server explorer (Server Explorer -> Add Connection -> Change -> Choose Data Source -> (MySQL Data Provider)). But it is not appearing in VS 2005.
Is there a fix / workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider not using textspeak here - we like properly written out words. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not getting your question clearly may be this will help you..

```
Check For Refernece to : System.Data.DataSetExtensions
```

### Code

```
 using System.Data.Odbc;

 private const string ConnStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.5 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=test;uid=root;pwd=;option=3";
```

Comment: ".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" is available when I am setting new connection from Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010. But it is not available in Visual Studio 2005.